# html pattern attribute not working using codeigniter form_open

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

Following is the view file where I've to do validation on pattern, regex is fine and working well on local machine, but when I implement it in codeigniter with form_open(I think this is the issue, not sure), its submitting the form even when pattern is wrong..

```
<?php echo form_open('Addons/add', array('id' => 'form_validation', 'method' => 'POST', 'class'=>'addon_form')); ?>

<input type="number" pattern="^\d{0,6}(\.\d{1,2})?$" name="pricing_price" class="padding-0 border-no col-md-10" style="margin: -26px 0px 7px 38px;" placeholder="" required>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

I'm also using jquery validate and AJAX on submit

```
      $('.addon_form').validate({

        submitHandler: function (form) 
        {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: BASE_URL + 'Addons/add',
                data: $('.addon_form').serialize(),
                success: function (html) 
                {

                    $('.addon_submit').text("Create Addon");
                    if(first[0] == 1)
                    {
                        //blah blah  
                    }

                },
                });
        },
       });
```

What might be the issue?

Comment: Do you have some errors in develop console?

Comment: No errors in developer console

Comment: `pattern` attribute doesn't work with `<input type="number">`